# ¿Cómo limpiar un formulario validado con jquery validate?

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-validate

tengo una consulta y es la siguiente:

Tengo un formulario dentro de un modal que es validado con JQuery Validate pero al momento de cerrar el modal y volver abrir el modal se queda con los estilos de validación puestos, y lo que deseo es que al abrir el modal aparezca mi formulario limpio.

Formulario

```
<div class="modal fade" id="modalNuevo" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="basicModal" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Basic Modal</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <form class="form-horizontal" action="#" id="formPersona">
                    <input type="hidden" name="idPersona" id="idPersona" enctype="multipart/form-data"/>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label col-sm-4" for="nombre">Nombre:</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-5">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nombre" name="nombre">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label col-sm-4" for="apellidos">Apellidos:</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-5">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="apellidos" name="apellidos">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label col-sm-4" for="edad">Edad:</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-5">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="edad" name="edad">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label col-sm-4" for="telefono">Telefono:</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-5">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="telefono" name="telefono">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
                
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="btnGuardar">Guardar</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="btnActualizar">Actualizar</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="btnCerrar">Cerrar</button>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Archivo js

```
$("#btnNuevo").click(function () {
                //Abre Modal de Registro
                $("#modalNuevo").modal("show");

                //Ocultar Boton Actualizar
                $("#btnActualizar").hide();

                //Mostrar Boton Guardar
                $("#btnGuardar").show();

                //Limpiar Cajas
                $("#idPersona").val("");
                $("#nombre").val("");
                $("#apellidos").val("");
                $("#edad").val("");
                $("#telefono").val("");

                //Habilitar Cajas
                $("#nombre").prop("readonly", false);
                $("#apellidos").prop("readonly", false);
                $("#edad").prop("readonly", false);
                $("#telefono").prop("readonly", false);

            });
```

Validación

```
validar: function () {

            var form1 = $("#formPersona");
            form1.validate({
                rules: {
                    nombre: "required",
                    apellidos: "required",
                    edad: {
                        required: true,
                        number: true
                    },
                    telefono: "required"
                },
                messages: {
                    nombre: "Por favor, ingrese su nombre",
                    apellidos: "Por favor, ingrese su nombre",
                    edad: {
                        required: "Por favor, ingrese su edad",
                        number: "Ingrese un número válido"
                    },
                    telefono: "Por favor, ingrese su telefono"
                },
                errorElement: "em",
                errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
                    // Add the `help-block` class to the error element
                    error.addClass("help-block");

                    // Add `has-feedback` class to the parent div.form-group
                    // in order to add icons to inputs
                    element.parents(".col-sm-5").addClass("has-feedback");

                    if (element.prop("type") === "checkbox") {
                        error.insertAfter(element.parent("label"));
                    } else {
                        error.insertAfter(element);
                    }

                    // Add the span element, if doesn't exists, and apply the icon classes to it.
                    if (!element.next("span")[0]) {
                        $("<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove form-control-feedback'></span>").insertAfter(element);
                    }
                },
                success: function (label, element) {
                    // Add the span element, if doesn't exists, and apply the icon classes to it.
                    if (!$(element).next("span")[0]) {
                        $("<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-ok form-control-feedback'></span>").insertAfter($(element));
                    }
                },
                highlight: function (element, errorClass, validClass) {
                    $(element).parents(".col-sm-5").addClass("has-error").removeClass("has-success");
                    $(element).next("span").addClass("glyphicon-remove").removeClass("glyphicon-ok");
                },
                unhighlight: function (element, errorClass, validClass) {
                    $(element).parents(".col-sm-5").addClass("has-success").removeClass("has-error");
                    $(element).next("span").addClass("glyphicon-ok").removeClass("glyphicon-remove");
                }
            }).form();

            if (form1.valid()) {
                persona.registrar();
            }
        },
```

Comment: Yo intentaria lo siguiente: comentaria o sacarias las lineas  $("#btnActualizar").hide(); y $("#btnGuardar").show(); a modo de pruebas y ves que pasa. Y mueve  $("#modalNuevo").modal("show") al final del código para ver si se ejectuta.

Comment: Tambien puedes intentar limpiar el documento registrando este evento que se ejecuta cuando se instancia el plugin y antes que sea visible y ahi metes el codigo de limpieza del formulario.
$('#modalNuevo').on('show.bs.modal', function (e) {
  // do something...
})

Comment: con los modales no hay problemas, son los estilos css de validación que se quedan puestos al abrir el modal.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes crear una función como esta

```
function clearValidationErrors() {

    var validator = $("#formPersona").validate();
    validator.resetForm();
    $("#divContainer .error").removeClass("error");
}
```

La cual puedes mandar llamar al principio de tu eventHandler

```
$("#btnNuevo").click(function () {
    clearValidationErrors();

    //Abre Modal de Registro
    $("#modalNuevo").modal("show");

    //El resto de tu código
```

Por cierto, cuando utilizas Bootstrap es recomendable tener un `container`. En mi caso, yo lo suelo incluir antes del form. En tu caso podría quedar así:

```
<div class="modal-body">
    <div id="divContainer" class="container" style="width: auto;">
        <form class="form-horizontal" action="#" id="formPersona">
```

Si te fijas, el nombre de mi div del **container** es que el mismo que estoy llamando en mi función `clearValidationErrors`. Lo que está haciendo esa línea es buscar la clase **error** en todos sus descendientes y quitarla.